# Wildcard mysql LIKE or IN array values issue

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have the following code block which explodes a string upon spaces.

```
$run = explode(" ",strtolower($q));
```

eg. "This is the string"

Array `$run` look like:

> (This,is,the,string)

The problems im having are:

I only want to `explode` the string if it has a white, something equal as using php function `str_word_count($q)`>1.

Unsure on how to create a single query which will work with multiple words in string and search table using any of them.

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM  `table1`  WHERE name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($run[0]) ."%' OR name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($run[1]) ."%'";
```

Trying to simplyfy the above query making it smaller and variable in size based on word count. Is this also a good aproach to exploding the string then preparing the sql?

I've tried using `IN` as well on SQL query with no good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's MATCH . . . AGAINST . . . to perform this kind of search:

```
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('this is the string')
```

Consult the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) for more information.

---

Original solution, not helpful in this situation:

You can check out the MySQL specific function FIND_IN_SET:

```
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(colname, 'This,is,the,string') > 0
```

The value in colname cannot contain a comma, however.